# Почему у меня тормозит отрисовка большого количества объектов opengl на телефоне?

Tags: java, android, opengl

При отрисовке 3000 вершин телефон уже начинает тормозить.

Вопрос: на что вообще способен средний телефон в наше время в плане графики?

Но 3000, кажется уж черезчур маленьким числом. Где-то слышал, что по миллиону частиц рисуют, а здесь... Если по коду: все атрибуты хранятся в vbo. Я даже делал флажок для теста, который запускал код, отвечающий за передачу параметров в шейдер всего один раз, а `glDrawArrays` каждый кадр. Тормоза продолжились, следовательно именно `glDrawArrays` делает плохо.

Comment: https://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html

Comment: аквариум так же плохо работает?

Comment: мой iphone se проседает по fps ниже 30 начиная с 10к рыб, но тут не только полигоны рисуются, как Вы понимаете..

Comment: На что способен "средний телефон" можно посмотреть из игр в Google Play. Проблемы в вашем приложении могут вызваны большим количеством причин, которые даже не стоит обсуждать тут.

Comment: Style-7, почему даже не стоит обсужать.

Comment: Stranger in the Q, на 1000 - 40fps, на 5000 - 14fps

Comment: Ну да, видимо у меня просто слабенький телефон)